# Approaches to help my stay at home mom get a full-time role?

Tags: job-search

As background, my mother has been a stay at home mom for almost 30 years. She has an engineering degree and had worked as an engineer before, and over the past three decades has been involved in various initiatives such as owning her own business, and holding leadership positions on boards of nonprofits and cultural clubs.

Recently, as a result of situations within our family, my mom wants to be able to work to provide for herself independently which I can completely understand and respect. I’d like to help her out as best I can, but I’m not sure the best way to approach this. I work in insurance (not sales), and was considering asking the HR department at my company if they have tips and suggestions for someone in her position, but I’m not sure if that reduces her chances to work at my company.

The issue is that my mom does not have specific experience in any certain field (such as claims, UW) but is more than willing to learn. I’d appreciate any advice anyone has in terms of ways to find full time roles that are open to career changers/returning caregivers. My mom isn’t looking to make 6figs, but have really to be able to have a way to support herself.

I would appreciate any advice anyone has, thanks so much.

Comment: What  do SAHM and UW mean ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 SAHM is stay-at-home mom, and since the questioner says they're in insurance, UW is likely underwriting.

Comment: Random bit: Common sense, ownership, and a good attitude (soft skills) are _really_ rare.  Don't be discouraged by the 30-year gap, even tho most people will probably not understand it.  Just need _one_.

Answer (score 4):

While vouching for your mother at work may be helpful, I think she would do well to look for a role that combines her engineering education (most of which will never go stale) with things she learned while running her business, running nonprofits, and running a household. This probably means management, whether an engineering-focused project manager or a more general manager-of-engineers. She can "speak their language" and relate to the problems they're facing in a way that non-engineers might not find easy, and specific deficiencies (like having never used a tool everyone in the discipline now uses, or not being up to date with certain laws and regulations) won't be as much of an issue as if she wanted a pure engineering position.

Big companies might insist on certifications for project managers and recent experience for managers. Small companies might be willing to take a chance on someone who knows how to get things done. I would have loved a "practice manager" to look after specific consulting projects and the people who were assigned to them. While small companies may be advertising for a role like this, many may not know they need one or can get one. So networking and telling companies "I could manage that for you" might be the key. Perhaps freelance at first, project by project? Join some organizations where bumping into possible clients, or people who work at places she could be hired, happens more often than not. Tell people what she can do and that she wants to do it. See where that goes.

Comment: Thanks! We had both considered this before, but she hasn’t been involved with engineering for 30 years which led her to look to other avenues. The project management route is really interesting though, that isn’t something I’d considered so I appreciate you bringing that up. I’ll definitely bring this up and see if I can try to convince others to take a chance.

Answer (score 3):

> over the past three decades has been involved in various initiatives

Her best option is to leverage her network from these activities for work.

The biggest asset as you get older isn't your 20 year old qualifications or willingness to work, or even your experience in many cases. It's your network.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably go ahead and ask HR and all departments in your company to see if they have any position for her with her current experiences and skills. Tell them she is willing to learn and can learn fast on the job (as I presume so, right ?).

Talk to the managers, team leads, and coworkers at your company, and ask them to provide her with advice to increase her chance of getting hired.

Look for jobs at other companies too.

---

BTW, it definitely won't reduce her chance of getting hired if you ask your HR about her situation and her job interest in your company.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate your advice.